# Is CacheFactory in angularjs a singleton?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've created a service using the CacheFactory. I was expecting it to be a singleton. I inject it into my controller and it works fine within the scope of the controller. But once I go to a different page with a different scope, I don't seem to have the values in the cache that I stored in the same controller in a different scope. Shouldn't the behavior of the CacheFactory be a singleton where I have those same cached objects everywhere I inject the CacheService?

This is my service as an example:

```
angular.module('MyService', []).factory('CacheService', function($cacheFactory) {
        return $cacheFactory('cacheService', {
            capacity: 3 // optional - turns the cache into LRU cache
        })
    });
```

Then in my controller:

```
function MyController($scope, CacheService) {
   var results= CacheService.get('storedvalue');
   if(!results){
       CacheService.put('storedvalue', results);
      alert('results not stored');
   }
   else
      alert('results stored');
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$cacheFactory` is actually not the service you want to use - it's a factory that you use to *create* the singleton service you want to use. Eyeballing your code, it seems like it should work. But I went ahead and created a demo to prove that it does. Here's the service:

```js
.factory('CacheService', function($cacheFactory) {
   var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheService', {
     capacity: 3 // optional - turns the cache into LRU cache
   });

   return cache;
});
```

In this example, `CacheService` *is* the singleton that has a local cache created with `$cacheFactory`, which is what we return from the service. We can inject this into any controller we want and it will always return the same values.

Here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/loKWGms1lMCnmiWa1QA7?p=preview

---

If for some reason your post doesn't contain what broke your code, please feel free to update my Plunker to break it and we can go from there.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Your example works. And now that I look closer mine does too. Where it doesn't work is if I refresh the browser. Which now that I think about it probably makes sense because it's bootstrapping angularjs again when I refresh the browser. So in that case it probably makes sense that I no longer have the values in the cache would you agree?

Comment: Yes, state is entirely bound to the current page load. AngularJS (and all client-side MVC frameworks) are intended to be used on single-page apps (though they are not limited to them). But you can use local storage to persist if you need to. You'll just have to write the service yourself.