# Don't understand the need for $cacheFactory if Factories are singletons

Tags: angularjs, singleton, factory, language-features, cachefactory

I'm relatively new to AngularJs and I'm trying to build a single page application with it. My application runs within a content management site. I have 3 factories for user, group and site functions.

I'm interested in using angular's $cacheFactory but I'm not sure what the benefit is if my data remains in the factory since it's a singleton.

For example, my user factory has an object called allUsers. This object is used through my application for different views. Intuitively, it seems like it's something that should be cached but I'm having a hard time understanding why since this object is in the user factory which can be access from any of my controllers.

Comment: Factory in angular is a singltone object that provides services to the controller / other factory etc. The $cacheFactory is a factory (meaning - a service) that provides cache services to the controller (or any other factory for that matter). You can use this factory to cache object as you please.

Comment: K so lets say my service/factory has an allUsers object, what's the benefit of getting that object from the cacheFactory instead of the user service/factory?

Comment: If you decide to cache your user object you should probably use the UserFactory to retrieve it from the cache and not use the cache factory directly from your controller.

Comment: So the benefit is just centralization of objects throughout my application then. Instead of having my controllers go through the factories to get objects, they can all go through the cacheFactory and get them from there.

Comment: It's a design decision. I think that your controllers should access the relevant objects through the relevant factory. If you decide in the future to work with no cache or a different cache you will only have to change the factories and no all the controllers. I'ts basic separation.

Comment: @haki I think I get the just of it. For now I don't really think it's beneficial to implement this into my application. I like the idea of getting my objects from where they are created, the factory. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is CacheFactory in angularjs a singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583403/is-cachefactory-in-angularjs-a-singleton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CacheFactory` is a factory:

> The purpose of the Factory Method pattern is to define an interface for creating an object but deferring instantiation of the object to subclasses.

which creates new instances each time an object of its type is created, unlike a Singleton:

> The intent of the Singleton pattern is to ensure that only one instance of a class is loaded, and that the instance provides a global point of access.

In Angular, the CacheFactory offers the following benefits over other solutions:

- Caches can be injected into a filter, unlike controller scopes
- Caches can be enumerated
- Caches can be easily destroyed or redefined
- Caches are not tied to digest data binding, unlike controller scopes
- Caches are not tied to browser permissions, unlike cookies or localStorage/sessionStorage

> I'm not sure what the benefit is if my data remains in the factory

CacheFactory offers the following features:

- 'should create cache with defined capacity'
- 'should blow away the entire cache via removeAll and start evicting when full'
- 'should correctly refresh and evict items if operations are chained'

But CacheFactory also has the following unexpected behaviors:

- 'should purge the next entry if the stalest one was removed'
- 'should only decrement size when an element is actually removed via remove'

**References**

- [Deep dive into JSF patterns](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-dsgnpatjsf/)
- [Factory method and MVC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/ora_as3_design_patterns.html)
- [AngularJS Source: cacheFactorySpec.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/test/ng/cacheFactorySpec.js)
- [Why is OOP Difficult?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16025/why-is-oop-difficult)
- [DCOM and CORBA Side by Side, Step By Step, and Layer by Layer](https://www.ime.usp.br/~reverbel/SOD-97/Textos/dcom_corba/Paper.html)