# AngularJS cacheFactory not working

Tags: angularjs

This is my code:

```
App.directive('topNav', function(API, $cacheFactory) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'packages/partials/includes/header.html',
        link: function($scope) {
            var cache = $cacheFactory('dataCache');

            if( cache !== undefined ) {
                API.data().success(function(data){
                    $scope.phone = data.phone;
                    $scope.mail = data.email;
                    cache.put('data', data);
                 });
            } else {
                $scope.phone = cache.get('data').phone;
                $scope.mail = cache.get('data').email;
                console.log(cache.get('data'));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is it always returns undefined and I really don't know what's going wrong, what may go wrong ?

Comment: Not sure why it would return undefined. Are you sure about that? A quick test (http://plnkr.co/edit/r30N4xNiToRbQslE31jP?p=preview), using 1.4.3, shows that trying to create the same cache twice (as you're doing, if the directive is used more than once) will throw an exception. Please come up with a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is CacheFactory in angularjs a singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583403/is-cachefactory-in-angularjs-a-singleton)