# update $cacheFactory from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, cachefactory

Is it possible to add values to my $resource $cacheFactory from my controller & keep this data in sync across multiple controllers?  Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is:

**1)** pull JSON resource from API

**2)** manipulate JSON as if it weren't a $resource anymore, just a plain JSON object that I can use between controllers.

Is there an "angular way" to do this or should I just cache the whole place list using local storage & read and write everything else from there?

```
.factory('places', ['$resource','environment','$cacheFactory',
    function($resource, environment, $cacheFactory) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('places');
        return $resource(environment.apis.places, {}, {
            query: {
                isArray:true,
                method: 'GET',
                cache: cache
            }
        });
    }
])

.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, places) {
    places.query({}, function(result){

        $scope.item = result[0]
    })

    $scope.makeFav = function(index){
        //add a new key to cached places data 
        $scope.item.fav = true
    }
}

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, places) {
    places.query({}, function(result){

        $scope.item = result  //should get the updated cache changed by ItemCtrl
    })

    console.log($scope.item[0].fav)  //should = true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is CacheFactory in angularjs a singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583403/is-cachefactory-in-angularjs-a-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Create a constant recipe
- Inject `cacheFactory`
- Create an instance of `cacheFactory`
- Inject the constant into each controller
- Reference the instance of `cacheFactory`
- Manipulate the instance of `cacheFactory` in each controller

  ```
  function sharedCache($cacheFactory)
     {
     var sharedCache = $cacheFactory.get('sharedCache') ? $cacheFactory.get('sharedCache') : $cacheFactory('sharedCache');

     return sharedCache;
     }

  function bar(sharedCache, $scope)
     {
     sharedCache.put('config', $scope.config);
     }

  bar.$inject = ['sharedCache', '$scope'];
  sharedCache.$inject = ['$cacheFactory'];

  angular.module('foo',[]);
  angular.module('foo').constant('sharedCache', sharedCache);
  angular.module('foo').controller('bar', bar);
  ```

**References**

- [AngularJS Documentation for iid](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$cacheFactory/iid#!)
- [ng-book: caching through HTTP](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Caching/)